# Checkout shipping summary doesn't display Region name at checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

In checkout page sidebar, there's a block that displays shipping information, based on the shipping address that customer uses.

[image]

The file that displays it is

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-informations/address-renderer/default.html
```

and it uses the following code:

```
<span html="address().region"></span>
```

Region is a selectbox that contains values like this:

```
<option data-title="Region A" value="570">Region A</option>
<option data-title="Region B" value="571">Region B</option>
<option data-title="Region C" value="572">Region C</option>
```

***`address().region` displays "571" instead of "Region B".***

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the area you are talking about. Cause I guess you are digging in a wrong file.

Comment: posted screenshot

Comment: @Korbin I think you're right, this is probably the wrong html file, but I can't find the right one. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I created a custom version of

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html
```

in my theme and **replaced**:

```
<span html="address().region"></span>
```

with

```
<text args="getStateName(address().region,address().countryId)"/>
```

I also created a custom version of file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.js
```

in my theme. There, I **added this new function**:

```
getStateName: function (stateId,countryId) {
    if (_.isEmpty(countryData())) {
        countryData(customerData.reload(['directory-data'], false));
    }
    var state_obj = countryData()[countryId].regions[stateId];

    return state_obj.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under theme with this path

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address/details.html

```
<div class="billing-address-details" data-bind="if: isAddressDetailsVisible() && currentBillingAddress()">
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko if: (currentBillingAddress().company) --><!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().company --><!-- /ko --><br/><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: currentBillingAddress().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
        <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value != null -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value == null -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute] --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<button type="button"
        class="action action-edit-address"
        data-bind="visible: !isAddressSameAsShipping(), click: editAddress">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
</button>
```

You should also add the following file

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

```
<!-- ko if: (visible()) -->
<!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko if: (address().company) --><!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko --><br/><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
        <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I set the region after

> currentBillingAddress().city -->,

Remember to flush cache and also deploy static content. As that is html file and it is static content. You can also try to remove generated/code.

Comment: `billing-address/details.html` is not the right file

Comment: @zekiaI updated my answer.